# How to flip orientation of Edges / Vertices

Tags: edges, geometry-nodes, transform-orientation

I have a little problem over here. I have imported a spline from Inventor to Blender. When i now extrude this spline over a geometry node - the face orientation of some faces are wrong.

Can i flip the orientation of the edge or can i only flip the orientation of faces himself?!

Thanks for your help :-D

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Why don't you use the node `Extrude` here, if you are dealing with a mesh?

Comment: I can use it, sure. But here i have a way bigger problem with the face orientation. half of the face are wrong there.

Comment: Then it could possibly help you (and us) if you share your file with us: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that you have 2 splines as i have with my two circles here:

[image]

you can "flip" just one spline by just using the negative value for the curve line and adjust it with transform afterwards like this:

[image]